# Error Failed to connect before the deadline running Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, caliper, hyperledger-caliper

When I run Hyperledger Caliper with Zookeper I get the following error:

[image]

I got this error in the client(different machine), obviously the address is not localhost, the address is the server ip.

When I go to logs, I can not see anything else...
Only failed to connect before the deadline error and endorsement error because timeout

Facts:

- I'm using virtualbox with bridge adapter network
- I can reach the server from client (I proved it doing ping from client to server)
- The ports are opened (I proved it using telnet)
- If run the test with local clients it runs well

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caliper's Zookeeper-based distributed client feature had a lot of problems, which is why it'll be removed in v0.2.0 and reimplemented in v0.3.0.
I know this doesn't answer your question, but for now, I'd suggest spawning local clients. If you need a really high send rate, then you'll need a lot of clients (client processes should wait a lot for I/O, so you don't need as many CPU cores as clients).